# Springboot fetching stale data from database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using JpaRepository in SpringBoot for an Entity. A service method runs and processes 100s of such entity. Time taken to process on entity is approx 30 seconds. At first, all entity would have status "IN_QUEUE". While the process is running, I can update the status of the entity to "CANCELLED" from a different endpoint. The service method has the logic to check the status of entity and if it is "CANCELLED", it shouldn't pick it up.

The issue is, the updated value is not visible to JpaRepository (or SpringBoot). I put the debug point, and called the repositories' fetch method. I updated the value directly in DB to "CANCELLED", but the SpringBoot still sees the value as "IN_QUEUE" only.

Is there any configuration which I need to do so that SpringBoot sees the updated value? If no, then is there any other way to achieve the "CANCELLED" feature?

Comment: The solution would be to configure your spring boot application for read-committed. Otherwise Hibernate uses the cached value and "don't see" the changes made by another application.